# How to differentiate between variables passed into function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm working on an automatic (runs until done without user input) blackjack game.

```
let randomDeal = () => {
  let cardOne = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  let cardTwo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  return cardOne + cardTwo;
}


let player = randomDeal();
let dealer = randomDeal();

console.log("Your hand: " + player);
console.log("Dealer's hand: " + dealer);

let hit = (hand) => {
  if (hand <= 16){
    hand += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log("Second hand: " + hand);
    if (hand <= 21){
      hand += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
      console.log("Third hand: " + hand);
    }
  }else{
    console.log("Stay: " + hand);
  }
}

hit(player);
hit(dealer);
```

So far it goes like this:

```
$ babel-node main.js
Your hand: 6
Dealer's hand: 4
Second hand: 11
Third hand: 19
Second hand: 10
Third hand: 15
```

I'm confused about how to pass both `player` and `dealer` into the hit function and have them return their values back as `player` and `dealer`. Right now it is hard to separate them.

IDEAL OUTPUT:

```
$ babel-node main.js
    Your hand: 6
    Dealer's hand: 4
    Your second hand: 11
    Your third hand: 19
    Dealer's second hand: 10
    Dealer's third hand: 15
```

Using an object?
Start:

```
let ob = {
  player: 0,
  dealer: 0
}
```

post function:

```
ob = {
  player: 18,
  dealer: 19
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, but you can return multiple values by returning either an object or an array.  `return {hand: hand, player: player};`

Comment: I've now cleaned it up a bit to better explain what I am attempting to get out

Comment: If you want a function to actually change a variable that you pass in, then the only way to do that is to pass in an object where the variables are properties on the object.  Then, you can change the properties on the object and the caller will see those changes too (or make the variables global or in a parent scope, but I assume that's not what you're asking).

Answer (score 1):

No, a function cannot differentiate between variables (or any other expressions) that were used to compute its arguments. It can only differentiate between values.

For your case, you should consider using a second parameter with the (genitive of the) name of the player:

```
function hit (hand, prefix) {
  if (hand <= 16) {
    hand += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(prefix+" second hand: " + hand);
    if (hand <= 21) {
      hand += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
      console.log(prefix+" third hand: " + hand);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(prefix+" stay: " + hand);
  }
}

hit(player, "Your");
hit(dealer, "Dealer's");
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity could you just return an array of the two items?

```
return [player, dealer];
```

Then in the calling function:

```
result = hit(player, dealer);
player = result[0];
dealer = result[1];
```

Comment: This won't associate a value with player or dealer?